# How to show control in transparent window?

Tags: c#, transparent

I have a window form with label and button control and I want to show label and button control in a transparent window form in C#.
Same like as preload SQL Server.

thank you in Advance.

Comment: you mean to say Splashscreen .?

Comment: Yes @AkshayJoy i want to show splashscreen but it will not close automatically it will close with the help of cancel button.
please help me!

Comment: then you can Create a Windows Form with Label and Button call the Form as first Form in the Applicatioon

Comment: @RichardEv I have tried with set the form opacity but it is also make transparent the form controls.

Comment: @AkshayJoy actually my transparent form2 will show after clicking  form1's button.

Comment: try to use `filter: alpha(opacity=100); opacity: 1.0` in style.

Comment: @Rahul I am taking about window form using VC#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on the form you set the `Form.TransparencyKey` property to something like magenta, then any parts of the form that are magenta will be transparent.

So you can make the form borderless, put in a splash screen image where the parts you want to be transparent are magenta - then when its run you'll just see the non-magenta parts of the image. Or you can make the forms background color magenta and any controls on the form will just be 'floating'. You need to be careful with any controls that use blending though as they may appear to have magenta colored edges and other artifacts.

Alternatively use WPF instead of Winforms for more control over the windows appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Opacity Poperty of Windows Form object,

**`frmSplasg.Opacity = 0.83;`**

Comment: I was tried but it will also make transparent the label and button controls

Comment: You can try this,But thus Extra Code Work http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1948/A-Shaped-Windows-Form-Application-with-Variable-Op